# Doing two animations on scroll

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I am using JavaScript to have a CSS animation start when the element is in the viewport:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element-one');
const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: .4
}
const callbacks = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting){
      entry.target.classList.add('element-one-animation');
    }
  });
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbacks, options);
elements.forEach(element => {
  observer.observe(element);
});
```

This works great. I tried adding a second animation on scroll:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element-two');
const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: .4
}
const callbacks = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting){
      entry.target.classList.add('element-two-animation');
    }
  });
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbacks, options);
elements.forEach(element => {
  observer.observe(element);
});
```

But this second one doesn't work. When I delete the first one, however, the second one does work. I'm not well versed in Javascript and I think it is just something that can't be repeated but I can't figure it out. Please help.